# CSS Stack divs after Jquery builds them

Tags: css

*Brief background: I am using Jquery to build Divs if there is information to be built.*

I have read a few threads today on stacking Divs, but everything I try just doesn't seem to work.

Given the following [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GjrX/) (That is what my current solution looks like)

I would like to stack the BAR 2 onto BAR 1, and then BAR 3 onto BAR 2, creating an end result like this:

```
BAR 3

BAR 2

BAR 1
```

I know this questions has been asked a lot before, but none of those threads helped me, so I thought I would show my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` from `.bar` and add some height to it.

Your fiddle updateded: http://jsfiddle.net/4GjrX/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="bars">
    <div class="bar-group">
       <div class="bar fig2">BAR3</div>  
       <div class="bar fig1">BAR2</div>
       <div class="bar fig0">BAR1</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Graph Bars */
.bars {
    height: 253px;
    width: 100%;
}
.bar-group {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 30px;
    width: 200px;
}
.bar {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;    
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Graph Bars */
.bars {

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.bar-group {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
     /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction:reverse;

    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-direction:reverse;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */

    -webkit-box-direction:reverse;

    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-direction:reverse;
    }
}
.bar {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}
.bar.fig0 {
    left: 0;
}
.bar.fig1 {
    left: 52px;
}
.bar.fig2 {
    left: 104px;
}
```